# Finding earliest connected value over two columns

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, redshift, recursive

I have a, perhaps slightly esoteric, use case.

Given a table like the following:

```
 id1 | id2 |      timestamp      
-----+-----+---------------------
   3 |   4 | 2016-03-22 09:52:15
   1 |   2 | 2016-03-22 12:05:28
   2 |   3 | 2016-03-22 11:55:56
   5 |   6 | 2016-03-22 11:58:23
   6 |   7 | 2016-03-22 09:51:54
```

I would like to "trace" each id in id1 to its oldest id2 where connection can span over id1 and id2. For instance in the above dataset I would like the resultset to contain:

```
1 |   4 | 2016-03-22 09:52:15
5 |   7 | 2016-03-22 09:51:54
```

The results should be ordered by the timestamp column.
And ideally no other occurrences of "1" and "5".

I am using **Amazon Redshift**, which imposes some limitations.

So far I have dabbled with using window functions combined with a self join:

```
SELECT t1.id1,
FIRST_VALUE(t2.id2) OVER (
   PARTITION BY t1.id1, (t1.id1=t2.id1 or t1.id2=t2.id2)
   ORDER BY t2.timestamp ASC
   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
)
FROM    test_decision t1
LEFT JOIN test_decision t2 ON t1.id1 = t2.id2
```

The general idea is to group based on logical expression (e.g. contains either id1 or id2), rather than partitioning only on rows with both. I've tried `SELECT ... GROUP BY` in a similar manner, but without getting the results I want.

I hope this use case makes sense to some of you.

In an effort to eliminate ambiguity: The rows are connected by having a value of id1 or id2  in either id1 or id2 columns of other rows. For instance, 1 leads to 4 through rows having (id1,id2) = (1,2),(2,3) and (3,4) in my example.

Regarding recursiveness: I think I can solve it by joining multiple times and coalescing the "outermost" value, my problem here is that the problem can be arbitrarily deep, e.g. I can solve this case by joining twice, but is there a way in SQL to get arbitrary recursion depth? And is that a good idea?

Comment: My question was why (for example) the `09:52:15` was chosen. Is it because it's the minimum of the three timestamps (`12:05:28`, `11:55:56`, `09:52:15`) of that group or because it's in the row of the "last" (`3->4`) transition of that group?

Comment: Why do you mention `And ideally no other occurrences of "1" and "5".` Can there be multiple roots for a single path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a recursive problem by nature. SQL introduced recursive CTEs for that purpose quite some time ago. Since Redshift does not seem to support this, your only remaining option to solve this *within* the database is a **user defined function** (UDF). It seems like [the only server-side language supported by Redshift is **`plpythonu`**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html).

Here is an old answer with a PL/pgSQL function and an rCTE implementing the same solution side-by-side. But it's using the default procedural language of Postgres: PL/pgSQL:

- [Loop in function does not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19309470/939860)

No idea why Redshift chose not to support PL/pgSQL.

Comment: Alright, thank you for what seems to be the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

I think you need a recursive query. Something like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
  groups (id1, id2, timestamp, level) AS   
    ( SELECT t.id1, t.id2, t.timestamp, 1 
      FROM test_decision AS t
      WHERE NOT EXISTS
            ( SELECT * 
              FROM test_decision AS p
              WHERE p.id2 = t.id1
            )
     UNION ALL
       SELECT g.id1, t.id2, t.timestamp, g.level + 1
       FROM groups AS g
         JOIN test_decision AS t
           ON g.id2 = t.id1 
    ) 
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id1) 
    id1, id2, timestamp
FROM groups 
ORDER BY id1, level DESC ;
```

You may have to modify the final `SELECT`, depending on what you want exactly for the `timestamp` result. The minimum value in a group or the one from the "latest" `id` (by latest I mean the `4` in the group `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4`, which is not necessarily the maximum id).

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it seems like a great solution in a newer version of postgres. However, I am stuck with redshift, which for the most part means postures 8.* constrains. One of the effects of this is that "with recursive" is sadly not supported

Comment: Oh, I hadn't notice the Redshift tag, sorry. Which Postgres is it based on? 8.3? Your query suggests that it at least has window functions, right?

Comment: It's a bit messy with regards to exactly which version, but generally it is somewhere around 8.4, with window functions, yes. There is a list of unsupported things here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html . I hope that helps, and thanks again